# How to Resolve Google Chrome Pixelating in Parallels Upon VM Resume

Tags: google-chrome, parallels

When I resume an Ubuntu VM in Parallels on Mac, for some reason Google Chrome is pixelated and I have to quit Google Chrome and launch it again to regain normal usage.

I'm not sure if this is a Parallels issue or a Google Chrome issue.

Any suggestions?

[image]